# A locked question is marked as a duplicate of an inferior canonical, under the old system

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions, locked-posts

The question [Python math is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950819) has been locked, apparently after warring over whether to delete it after being marked as a duplicate.

I agree that it is a fine signpost and should not be deleted. However:

- The question was closed under the old system.
- The duplicate target, [Python rounding error with float numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997027), is now itself a duplicate of the canonical [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004).

I have been trying to fix such old closures as part of curating the site's best content. However, I am unable to do this now because of the lock.

What can I do?

Comment: Flag for moderator attention, and explain why you want the post unlocked.

Comment: Now unlocked. //

Comment: "Python math is wrong". That'll generate some traffic for the company, there is no way you're not going to click on that.

Comment: @Gimby I should adjust it to say floating-point, but otherwise people aren't going to find the question because of a *different* problem. I care about clickbait when it ends up sending people to an irrelevant Q&A.

Comment: I agree. The clickbait is the signpost.